# Is there a way to look for a part of a string ('USD' in 'USDSEK') in the keys of a dictionary and if found return the value?

Tags: python, dictionary

We can model current exchange rates with a provided dictionary

> > > exchange_rates['USDSEK']
> > > 10

Use that dictionary to define a method in the class that converts a given currency to the base currency

> > > mca.conversion_rate('USD')
> > > 10

**#This is the dictionary I'm trying to access**

```
exchange_rates = {'USDSEK': 10, 'EURSEK': 10}
```

**#Here my logic is mostly that if I find the given currency in the key I will return the value of the same key position**

```
def conversion_rate(self, given_currency):
    self.given_currency = given_currency
    for key in exchange_rates.keys():
        if given_currency in exchange_rates.keys():
            er = (exchange_rates[key]).values()
            return er
```

**#Assertion gives the USD currency and according to the dictionary it should be 10**

```
mca = MultiCurrencyAccount('SEK')
assert mca.conversion_rate('USD') == 10, f"{mca.conversion_rate('USD')=} != 10"
```

**#But when I run it it appears the following**

AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [193], in <cell line: 2>()
1 mca = MultiCurrencyAccount('SEK')
----> 2 assert mca.conversion_rate('USD') == 10, f"{mca.conversion_rate('USD')=} != 10"

AssertionError: mca.conversion_rate('USD')=None != 10

Comment: I believe you want `if given_currency in key:`, instead of `if given_currency in exchange_rates.keys():`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If possible, I'd advise you to restructure your data. Have two separate dicts for conversion from and conversion to, and split the string before insertion. This might take more memory, but it will be considerably faster if the database is large enough.

If that's not possible, you can do this:

```
for key, value in exchange_rate.items():
    if currency in key:
        return value
```

(You might use a different comparison like `.startswith`)